# MongoDB MR, silently drops records in midway

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I am running a MR on mongodb, It silently drops records when I try to do a denormalize operation on 10000 records, it happens somewhere in the middle of the collections (~5K). I tried removing near by records (when sorted), its nothing wrong with the data.

Here is my code

```
mapOrd = function() {
    var values = {
        customerId: this.customerId,
        orderNr: this.orderNr,
        productId: this.productId
    };
    emit(this.productId, values);
};

mapPrd = function() {
    var values = {
    code: this.code
    };
    emit(this.id, values);
};

reduceOrdPrd =  function(k, values) {
    var result = {};
    values.forEach(function(value) {
    var field;
        if ("orderNr" in value) {
            if (!("cust_ids" in result)) {
                result.cust_ids = [];
            }
            result.cust_ids.push(value);
        } else {
    for (field in value) {
        if (value.hasOwnProperty(field) ) {
                result[field] = value[field];
        }
         };  
       }
      });
       return result;
};



db.prd_ord.drop();

db.order_10000.mapReduce(mapOrd, reduceOrdPrd, {"out": {"reduce": "prd_ord"}, "sort": {"productId": 1}});
```

I am running this on a machine which has very low config. 512 MB RAM with 1GB of SWAP memory.

But whatever the case, it should not silently (randomly) drop elements of groups.

The objects are not exceeding the BSON object limit.(just 10 to 15 array of objects per key).

Any thoughts??

Comment: Are there any replicas set? In my case records where missing when map reduce where not waiting for data propagation to all replicas.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the first reduce for a key. It will execute following codes in loop,

```
if ("orderNr" in value) {
    if (!("cust_ids" in result)) {
        result.cust_ids = [];
    }
    result.cust_ids.push(value);
}
```

then get and return following

```
resut = {
    cust_ids : [ {
        customerId : customerId1,
        orderNr : orderNr1,
        productId : productId1
    }, {
        customerId : customerId2,
        orderNr : orderNr2,
        productId : productId2
    }, {
        customerId : customerId_n,
        orderNr : orderNr_n,
        productId : productId_n
    } ]
}
```

For the second reduce `on the same key`, assume there are 2 elements with the structure as above in values; definitely they will be handled with codes

```
for (field in value) {
    if (value.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
        result[field] = value[field];
    }
}
```

Because they have the same key **"cust_ids"** so only the last one will be left. All previous ones will be covered and dropped.

Comment: The code is working as designed. The only issue is dropping records with in same group at a particular point 5500 records in my code.

Comment: @Vipul Mehta, Your code will do dropping if many records on same key, but if less than 100 records for every key, there will be no drop. You can try it.

Comment: I have only 10-15 elements. And its not crossing BSON object limit. I just suspect some kind of commit happening even when the MR is iterating for emit key.

Comment: @Vipul Mehta, I post another answer for your information.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Wizard for your response.

My code is working as designed. The only issue is dropping records for same emit key at a particular point after 5500 records in my code. e.g. productid=553 (emit key) has 12 elements.which is ending at 5502 nd record in input collection order_10000. 5501st and 5502nd record is getting dropped from the output of MR.

Input Order_10000:

```
db.order_10000.find({productId:553}).pretty();
{
       "_id" : ObjectId("53f75e2ab4e41522bccf3410"),
       "customerId" : NumberLong(5699),
       "productId" : NumberLong(553),
       "orderNr" : NumberLong(6000058)
}
{
       "_id" : ObjectId("53f75e2ab4e41522bccf3411"),
       "customerId" : NumberLong(5699),
       "productId" : NumberLong(553),
       "orderNr" : NumberLong(6000059)
}
{
       "_id" : ObjectId("53f75e2ab4e41522bccf3412"),
       "customerId" : NumberLong(5699),
       "productId" : NumberLong(553),
       "orderNr" : NumberLong(6000060)
}
{
       "_id" : ObjectId("53f75e2ab4e41522bccf3413"),
       "customerId" : NumberLong(5699),
       "productId" : NumberLong(553),
       "orderNr" : NumberLong(6000061)
}
{
       "_id" : ObjectId("53f75e2ab4e41522bccf3414"),
       "customerId" : NumberLong(5699),
       "productId" : NumberLong(553),
       "orderNr" : NumberLong(6000062)
}
{
       "_id" : ObjectId("53f75e2eb4e41522bccf3415"),
       "customerId" : NumberLong(5699),
       "productId" : NumberLong(553),
       "orderLineNr" : NumberLong(1),
       "orderNr" : NumberLong(6000063)
}
{
       "_id" : ObjectId("53f75e2eb4e41522bccf3416"),
       "customerId" : NumberLong(5699),
       "productId" : NumberLong(553),
       "orderNr" : NumberLong(6000064)
}
{
       "_id" : ObjectId("53f75e2eb4e41522bccf3417"),
       "customerId" : NumberLong(5699),
       "productId" : NumberLong(553),
       "orderNr" : NumberLong(6000065)
}
{
       "_id" : ObjectId("53f75e2eb4e41522bccf3418"),
       "customerId" : NumberLong(5699),
       "productId" : NumberLong(553),
       "orderNr" : NumberLong(6000066)
}
{
       "_id" : ObjectId("53f75e97b4e41522bccf3419"),
       "customerId" : NumberLong(5699),
       "productId" : NumberLong(553),
       "orderNr" : NumberLong(6000067)
}
{
       "_id" : ObjectId("53f75e97b4e41522bccf341a"),
       "customerId" : NumberLong(5699),
       "productId" : NumberLong(553),
       "orderNr" : NumberLong(6000068)
}
{
       "_id" : ObjectId("53f76127b4e41522bccf341e"),
       "customerId" : NumberLong(5699),
       "productId" : NumberLong(553),
       "orderNr" : NumberLong(6000071)
}
```

Output of MR:

```
db.prd_ord.find({'value.cust_ids.productId': 553}).pretty();
{
       "_id" : NumberLong(553),
       "value" : {
               "cust_ids" : [
                       {
                               "customerId" : NumberLong(5699),
                               "orderNr" : NumberLong(6000068),
                               "productId" : NumberLong(553)
                       },
                       {
                               "customerId" : NumberLong(5699),
                               "orderNr" : NumberLong(6000067),
                               "productId" : NumberLong(553)
                       },
                       {
                               "customerId" : NumberLong(5699),
                               "orderNr" : NumberLong(6000066),
                               "productId" : NumberLong(553)
                       },
                       {
                               "customerId" : NumberLong(5699),
                               "orderNr" : NumberLong(6000065),
                               "productId" : NumberLong(553)
                       },
                       {
                               "customerId" : NumberLong(5699),
                               "orderNr" : NumberLong(6000064),
                               "productId" : NumberLong(553)
                       },
                       {
                               "customerId" : NumberLong(5699),
                               "orderNr" : NumberLong(6000063),
                               "productId" : NumberLong(553)
                       },
                       {
                               "customerId" : NumberLong(5699),
                               "orderNr" : NumberLong(6000062),
                               "productId" : NumberLong(553)
                       },
                       {
                               "customerId" : NumberLong(5699),
                               "orderNr" : NumberLong(6000061),
                               "productId" : NumberLong(553)
                       },
                       {
                               "customerId" : NumberLong(5699),
                               "orderNr" : NumberLong(6000060),
                               "productId" : NumberLong(553)
                       },
                       {
                               "customerId" : NumberLong(5699),
                               "orderNr" : NumberLong(6000059),
                               "productId" : NumberLong(553)
                       }
               ],
               "cust_ids_length" : 10
       }    
}
```

Next group starts fine from here. Same thing happens if a particular group crosses next threshold.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I missed some important information from your question such as `(just 10 to 15 array of objects per key)`. It should not occur that weird thing if the `sort:{productId:1}` works fine based on asc/desc type index. But please check whether there is more than one time of reduce calling for a same key, it will fail if happened on your code design.

I redesign the procedure as following and maybe it can help you.

```
mapOrd = function() {
    var values = {cust_ids: [{
        customerId: this.customerId,
        orderNr: this.orderNr,
        productId: this.productId
    }]};
    emit(this.productId, values);
};

reduceOrdPrd = function(k, values) {
    var result = [];
    values.forEach(function(value) {
        value.cust_ids.forEach(function(e) {
            result.push(e);
        });
    });
    return {cust_ids: result};
};

db.prd_ord.drop();

db.order_10000.mapReduce(mapOrd, reduceOrdPrd, {"out": {"reduce": "prd_ord"}, "sort": {"productId": 1}});
```

To help you to discover where confuse you , I rewrite your `map function` as below:

```
reduceOrdPrd = function(k, values) {
    var result = {};
    var reduceNum = 1;  // if it's larger than 1 in the last output, dropping is possible for this key.
    var reduceBatches = [values]; // record all batches of values used to call this reduce function. It would not lose data on this design.
    values.forEach(function(value) {
        if ("reduceNum" in value) {
            reduceNum += value.reduceNum;
            value.reduceBatches.forEach(function(e) {reduceBatches.push(e);});
        }
        var field;
        if ("orderNr" in value) {
            if (!("cust_ids" in result)) {
                result.cust_ids = [];
            }
            result.cust_ids.push(value);
        } else {
            for (field in value) {
                if (field != "reduceNum" && field != "reduceBatches") {
                    if (value.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
                        result[field] = value[field];
                    }
                }
            }
            ;
        }
    });
    result.reduceNum = reduceNum;
    result.reduceBatches = reduceBatches;
    return result;
};
```

Above would not change your original design but will add two fields into `value` per key. The output resembles like:

```
db.prd_ord.find({'value.cust_ids.productId': 553}).pretty();
{
       "_id" : NumberLong(553),
       "value" : {
                "reduceNum":<num>,
                "reduceBatches": [[], [], ...]
               "cust_ids" : [
                       {
                               "customerId" : NumberLong(5699),
                               "orderNr" : NumberLong(6000068),
                               "productId" : NumberLong(553)
                       },
                       {
                               "customerId" : NumberLong(5699),
                               "orderNr" : NumberLong(6000067),
                               "productId" : NumberLong(553)
                       },
                       ...
                ]
       }
}
```

Comment: This code seemed to work for me. :) Thanks a lot Wizard for your help, but my code is still a mystery. I logged a ticket for my issue. Lets see.
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15004

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Vipul Mehta, I suspect mongodb makes a reduce for the key when it collects 10 records sometimes because it never expected someone will run it in a machine with only 512MB RAM! :) By the way, your code doesn't confirm the requirements of reduce function design. You can find the information in the manual. **Normally, it will be safe only reduce function returns the very data structure which is same as the one sent by emit() function.** Values of `the same key` probably will be reduced more than one time.

Comment: @Vipul Mehta, I added something for you to investigate the reason that confused you. See above.

Comment: What are we assigning to "reduceNum" in mapper?

Comment: Nothing to do for `reduceNum` in mapper. This variable used to record how many times `reducer` has been called by system for specific key. As I mentioned, your code will probably cause dropping records if `reduceNum` is larger than one. `reduceNum` and `reduceBatches` will not be seen at final output if the key has only one original record, because `reducer` will not be called by system at this situation.

Comment: Thanks Wizard. I tried debugging with the reduceNum variable.No luck. The only thing which I can think of is that there are multiple threads running in the back ground and not able to merge them when I have diff structures in reduce function than the one sent from emit of mapper.

Comment: Single thread for mapreduce process unless you create new thread for it manually. It should be executed correctly even if there are multiple threads running. What's the results of `reduceNum` and `reduceBatches`?